# Using an output of aformula in another

Tags: excel, vba

Someone here posted this formula as an answer to the qustion how can one use a formula to know how many cells were used to create a merged cell:

```
Public Function MergeSize(r As Range) As Long
    MergeSize = r(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count
End Function
```

The formula works great, and I would like to use it's output into an `If` >> `Then` argument.

For example if the output is smaller than 10 then multiply by 70. If its bigger than 10 then multiply it by 65 and so on.

Comment: Welcome to [so], please take a [tour] and check [ask] first.  After that, may be you can show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See edited answer for to Function to serve as **UDF**.

```
Public Function MergeSize(r As Range) As Long

MergeSize = r(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count

If MergeSize <= 10 Then
    MergeSize = MergeSize * 70
Else
    MergeSize = MergeSize * 65
End If

End Function
```

How it is applied to in an Excel Sheet:

(In this example, Since "B2" consist of 8 merged cells, you multiply `8 * 70 = 560`.)

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your response (if equal to 10 than do the same as if smaller than 10), though I'm not sure how it would be used for any range of cells.  
With the formula I attached, I can click on a merged cell, and get the number of cells creating as an output. Is there a, behind the scenes, way to get this number into that if >> than argument?

Comment: @Eran are you talking about a **UDF** ? you want to call this Function from an Excel Sheet Cell (OR range) ?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry if I didn't explain myself better before. My aim is to click a merged cell from an excel sheet when Each cell in a merged cell on our syatem represents a day. According to the number of days the bill will be calculated.  For 10 days or less 70 and for more than that 65. 
I would like the total price to be presented in a popup window, but I think I can figure out that part by myself.

Comment: Works great! Toda!

Comment: @Eran Tesamen v next to my answer

Comment: I did, but I when i do i get thia message:Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: This is for the plus ^ sign, no? Not for the v

Comment: @Eran Toda, "Ezlahta" :)

Comment: Toda leha shoov!:)