# Using a formula in a sub

Tags: excel, vba

My original question was how to use a function's output in an if-->then statement, and Shai's help was very helpful (here: [Using an output of aformula in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693080/using-an-output-of-aformula-in-another)).

What I would like to do now, though, is to use this function in a sub. So I have this sub (which is not complete for now):

```
Private Sub CommandButto1_click()
Dim answer As Integer
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim late As VbMsgBoxResult

answer = MsgBox("Price for only one product?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Payment")
If answer = vbYes then
   late = MsgBox("Is the customer late and has to be charged extra?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)

   If late = vbYes then 
       MsgBox "mergesize function here"
   End If
End If

End Sub
```

It works fine as it is, but where it says - MsgBox "mergesize function here" is where I would like to add my function that looks like this:

```
Public Function MergeSize(r As Range) As Long

MergeSize = r(1).MergeArea.Cells.Count

If MergeSize <= 10 Then
    MergeSize = MergeSize * 70
Else
    MergeSize = MergeSize * 65
End If

End Function
```

Another side question is can I send the output of the function to null and have it only displayed in a msgbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the code below.
Iv'e marked where I added the code that calls the `Function MergeSize`. I've used `Range("B2")` as the Merged Range.

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButto1_click()

Dim answer As Integer
Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim late As VbMsgBoxResult

answer = MsgBox("Price for only one product?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "Payment")
If answer = vbYes Then
   late = MsgBox("Is the customer late and has to be charged extra?", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel)

   If late = vbYes Then
        '===== Added the 3 lines below =====
        Dim ExtraCharge As Long

        ExtraCharge = MergeSize(Range("B2")) '<-- Range("B2") is a Merged Cells
        ' === Ver 2.0 - to use with ActiveCell ===
        ExtraCharge = MergeSize(ActiveCell) '<-- ActiveCell is a Merged Cells

        MsgBox "Extra Charge is " & ExtraCharge
   End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again, Shai! I didnt really understand how to use this formula. I keep getting a return value of 1 (im guessing of B2). Is there a way to have it applyed to any merged cells block that I point to with my mouse?

Comment: @Eran you want to use `ActiveCell` ? the cell you select with your mouse ? if that's the case use `ExtraCharge = MergeSize(ActiveCell)` , see edited code (and remove the previous one in your code)

Comment: @Eran  hahaha, ten li V

Comment: Sorry. Im new to this... Asiti!:)